# Updating a dictionary with values and predefined keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, updates, xlrd

I want to create a dictionary that has predefined keys, like this:

```
dict = {'state':'', 'county': ''}
```

and read through and get values from a spreadsheet, like this:

```
for row in range(rowNum):
    for col in range(colNum):
```

and update the values for the keys 'state' (`sheet.cell_value(row, 1)`) and 'county' (`sheet.cell_value(row, 1)`) like this:

```
dict[{}]
```

I am confused on how to get the state value with the state key and the county value with the county key. Any suggestions?

Desired outcome would look like this:

```
>>>print dict
[
 {'state':'NC', 'county': 'Nash County'}, 
 {'state':'VA', 'county': 'Albemarle County'}, 
 {'state':'GA', 'county': 'Cook County'},....
]
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Solutions may vary depending upon whether your version preserves insertion order for dictionaries.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "how to get the state value with the state key and county value with the county key"?

Comment: As I iterate through the for loop, I am getting values under 2 column headings: State (with an index of 1) and County (with an index of 3). I want to go through each row and place the State values in the dictionary with the 'state' key and the County values from the county column with the 'county' key in the dictionary. Then it will move on to the next row and do the same thing. In essence I will have a 'list' of dictionaries for each state and county pair in a row. So, my dictionary will be empty at first: `dict = {'state':'', 'county': ''}` and be populated with respective values as it loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raqib's answer is partially correct but had to be modified for use with an actual spreadsheet with row and columns and the `xlrd` mod. What I did was first use `xlrd` methods to grab the cell values, that I wanted and put them into a list (similar to the `spreadsheet` variable raqib has shown above). Not that the parameters `sI` and `cI` are the column index values I picked out in a previous step. `sI=StateIndex` and `cI=CountyIndex`

```
list =[]
for row in range(rowNum):
    for col in range(colNum):
        list.append([str(sheet.cell_value(row, sI)), str(sheet.cell_value(row, cI))])
```

Now that I have a list of the states and counties, I can apply raqib's solution:

```
list_of_headings = ['state', 'county']
fipsDic = []
print len(list)
for i in range(len(list)):
    temp = {}
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        tempDic[list_of_headings[j]] = list[i][j]

    fipsDic.append(temp)
```

The result is a nice dictionary list that looks like this:

```
[{'county': 'Minnehaha County', 'state': 'SD'}, {'county': 'Minnehaha County', 'state': 'SD', ...}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a few assumptions regarding your question. You mentioned in the comments that State is at index 1 and County is at index 3; what is at index 2? I assumed that they occur sequentially. In addition to that, there needs to be a way in which you can map the headings to the data columns, hence I used a list to do that as it maintains order.

```
# A list containing the headings that you are interested in the order in which you expect them in your spreadsheet
list_of_headings = ['state', 'county']
# Simulating your spreadsheet
spreadsheet = [['NC', 'Nash County'], ['VA', 'Albemarle County'], ['GA', 'Cook County']]
list_of_dictionaries = []

for i in range(len(spreadsheet)):
    dictionary = {}
    for j in range(len(spreadsheet[i])):
        dictionary[list_of_headings[j]] = spreadsheet[i][j]
    list_of_dictionaries.append(dictionary)

print(list_of_dictionaries)
```

Comment: When I try to apply this solution, I keep getting an `IndexError: list index out of range.` This is more of a horizontal approach, whereas I am reading through a spreadsheet and my `i` = a row and `j` is more of a vertical column index value. Also my spreadsheet cell values will be like `sheet.cell_value(row, 1)` and `sheet.cell_value(row, 1)`. I'll have to work with this a bit, but I think this is on the right track. It seems like an indexing issue on my end.